# Interpretation of Kaplan-Meier curves with several groups in R

Tags: r, kaplan-meier

Got an assignment that we should interpret different Kaplan-Meier curves and the ouput from R looks like this:
[image: Kaplan-Meier survival data for different risk groups]
. The P-value tells us if the Groups are significantly different from eachother(correct?), but how do you interpret this value when there are several different Groups? That all Groups are significantly different from each other?

EDIT: This is the part of the code used to make the curve:

```
km.5 <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ hi.risk, data=diabetic)
ggsurvplot(km.5, pval=TRUE)
```

If there is more info I could provide to make it easier to answer the question let me know and I will add.

Comment: I am not an expert in survival analysis but it would be helpful if you told us which test you have used, i.e. what is the R command that you used in order to produce these curves?

Comment: @FabianWerner Thank you for your comment, I added what I believe is the relevant code. If I'm still missing some info needed to answer the question let me know and I will add.

Comment: I do not know why this question was closed... I think it is totally on topic (will upvote).